# Assembly code to read two integers (from 0-9), then compute and print their sum

Tags: assembly, masm, dosbox

I'm trying to add two numbers from the user and display their sum but I don't get the desired output.I don't know what I did wrong. Can someone please help? Here's my code:

```
Data_segment_name  segment  para 
n1 db ?
n2 db ?
Data_segment_name ends

Stack_segment_name segment para stack
Stack_segment_name ends

Code_segment_name segment 

Main_prog  proc far
    assume SS:Stack_segment_name,CS:Code_segment_name,DS:Data_segment_name

    mov AX,Data_segment_name         ; load the starting address of the data
    mov DS,AX                        ; segment into DS reg. 

    mov ah,01h
    int 21h

    sub al,30h
    mov n1,al

    mov ah,01h
    int 21h

    sub al,30h
    mov n2,al

    mov al,n1
    add al,n2

    mov ax,0h
    mov bl,10
    div bl

    mov dl,ah
    add dl,30h
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    mov dl,al
    add dl,30h
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    ;mov ax,4c00h                     ; exit program
    mov ah,07h
    int 21h

Main_prog      endp 
Code_segment_name   ends
               end Main_prog
```

Answer (score 1):

You assume that the results of the division will stay in the registers while you display your first digit.

It will not, so you have to store the result to memory, just like you do with the input.

Comment: Yes i tried that and it works now, thanks a lot :) @BoPersson